# How to get a query odered by N of matching taxonomies?

Tags: taxonomy, query

How can I get a wp query that is sorted by how many tags (in my case) match a specified list? I want to retrieve a list of posts that match the category of the current post (which is a plain filter) but that are ordered from the highest number of matching tags to the lowest. Is it too much resource intensive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native function which to accomplish what you need. The only possible solution that I can think of is to make use of [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the returned array of posts from your custom query

You will need to do the following:

- Set you list with the desired tags
- Get a list of the tags a post belongs to
- Return an array with all the tags that match the two arrays
- Count the tags, and store the tag count in an array
- Sort your array and loop through the posts again and display as normal

The functions used here are as follows

- [`get_the_tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags)
- [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
- [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)
- [`wp_list_pluck`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck)

Here is an example code. Modify as needed

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'cat' => 'YOUR_CATID',
);
$q = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $q->have_posts() ) {
$count = [];
$count1 = [];

    while( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();

        $posttags = get_the_tags();
        if( $posttags ) {
            $tag_slugs = wp_list_pluck( $posttags, 'slug' );
            $relevant_tags = array('tag1', 'tag2', 'etc which translates to end of thought capacity' );
            $matched_tags = array_intersect( $tag_slugs, $relevant_tags );
            $count[$post->ID] = count( $matched_tags );
        }else{
            $count[$post->ID] = 0;
        }
    }

    usort( $q->posts, function ($a, $b) use($count) {

        return ($count[$a->ID] < $count[$b->ID]) ? 1 : -1;

    });

    rewind_posts();

    while( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();

        //Display your loop elements

    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry for not replying, I ended up using the code found here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/not-working-on-custom-post-types-2?replies=7, maybe slow on performance to a degree but does not seem that bad to me, also I am still not heavy caching, I also made this compatible network wide with a few modification and an external plugin. I do not quite remember why I did not use the code suggested here, the code uses usort the same